# Print From Android App

Tags: android, web-services, c#-4.0

Hello i am trying to print from android application.
 I have one desktop application that connect with android app.and that software is published on IIS server and i have created web-service in android.and when i am sending data to print it gets printer name of desktop application from database but print cant goes but when i am printing from software it works

```
 public void print_kot(GridView dgv)
      {

          string menuName = "",categoryType="";
          koGridview = dgv;


              //Get Printer name here
              cn.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select value from tbl_option where grp='KOT Printer'", cn);
          try
          {
              if (cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "")
                  PrinterName = "0";
              else
                  PrinterName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

          }
          cn.Close();
          PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
          pdoc = new PrintDocument();

          PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
          Font font = new Font("Courier New", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);


          PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);



          pd.Document = pdoc;
          pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
          pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 1000;

          pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 520;

          //Assign Printer name here

          PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
          pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = (PrinterName);

          pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(kot);

          pdoc.Print();

      }
```

Comment: please help me for this